# jsonp crossbrowser mistakes from domain or code side

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-browser, jsonp

im newbie in api and json getting data so i have a question regarding of getting the information by using `jsonp` from my website: `http://pda.bilgiteknolojileri.net/` i know that the domain name is pda not the api :) this is not my mistake though, not my domains, but i can moderate them, anyway i have a code:

```
    var url='http://pda.bilgiteknolojileri.net';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(cats) {
            $.each(cats.data, function(i, data) {
                var cat=data.cat;
                var cat_id=data.cat_id;
                $('#category').append('<option value="'+cat_id+'">'+cat+'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
```

as far as i understand the code is ok, but there is a mistake in console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and second not big mistake `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html` what im doing wrong? is it the cross-browser mistake from the domain side or mine in code?

**Request Headers:**

```
GET /?callback=jQuery182007281651743687689_1382452295311&_=1382452295320 HTTP/1.1
Host: pda.bilgiteknolojileri.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: tr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
Cookie: fbm_224237501004640=base_domain=.bilgiteknolojileri.net; CFID=337971; CFTOKEN=5130db21daca4ae5-BE9FEE21-0FA8-399A-7485246A32933BCE; JSESSIONID=7030f7b10f91d2d2d0ce10456f5c7a302350; WRK_COOKIE_ID=BE9FF125%2DA082%2D5206%2DD01747735EADD58B; __utma=56243896.53108638.1381244578.1382443118.1382450419.21; __utmc=56243896; __utmz=56243896.1381244578.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

**Query string parameters**

```
callback:jQuery182007281651743687689_1382452295311
_:1382452295320
```

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 14:19:24 GMT
```

The problem is that the response is in text/html format, where it should be javascript/application, what should i change? i cant get any data at all...
thank you for the help!

Comment: Possibly related: [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: @megawac if i change the `dataType` to `json` then i get a mistake: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`

Comment: Whats response are you getting from the server

Comment: @megawac do u mean this? RESPONSE HEADERS: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 14:19:24 GMT

Comment: Alright can you add a preview of the response in your question

Comment: Sorry, I meant the data response - it should look something like `jQuery17108861840174067765_1382451880471(data)` can you verify this

Comment: @megawac here it is: `callback:jQuery182007281651743687689_1382452295311
_:1382452295320`

Comment: You have to set `jsonp`
 headers in the requested file to debug `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Comment: @wumm u mean to set instead of `jsonp` to `json` if so, i have a mistake `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` or what should i do exactly? )

Comment: @venom Oh no that was a typo. I meant to set the content header just to jsonp because in your response headers there it says: `Content-Type: text/html;` and that's the reason for the second error message.

Comment: @wumm sorry, i didnt understand ) can u be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I told you some (in that case) useless things. You can't do ajax calls JSONP calls on sites which are not made for that.

Comment: @wumm i see so u mean i cant get data from my website unless i let the cross-browsing on it?

Comment: I think so, but I'm haven't often worked with JSONP, maybe there's a way.

Comment: Are you trying to call json on another domain? Because it might be a problem of cross-origin resource sharing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @pith i know, that's why im using `JSONP` instead of `JSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The server response header is claiming a mime-type of `text/html`
2. The server isn't responding with a JSONP object. This is the biggest issue.

The server is wrapping your JSON object with HTML. If you look at the response body from:
http://pda.bilgiteknolojileri.net/?callback=jQuery182007281651743687689_1382452295311&_=1382452295320

You'll see that it starts with:

```
<html>
    <head><meta ...
```

That first `<` is what's causing the unexpected token error.

Your server needs to respond with something more like this:

```
jQuery182007281651743687689_1382452295311({...JSON OBJECT...})
```

A little more explanation can be found here: [Confused on how a JSONP request works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193085/confused-on-how-a-jsonp-request-works)

It was mentioned before, but your question is almost a duplicate to this one: [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

The difference being that instead of just a JSON object being sent over, an html document with the JSON **INSIDE** it was sent over.